# Apache UseCanonicalName On isnt passing ServerName to CGI

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.4

On Apache 2.4 in in a virtualhost I have:

```
UseCanonicalName On
ServerName somename
ServerAlias www.someothername.com
```

According to the docs:

> With UseCanonicalName On Apache will use the hostname and port
>   specified in the ServerName directive to construct the canonical name
>   for the server. This name is used in all self-referential URLs, and
>   for the values of SERVER_NAME and SERVER_PORT in CGIs.

So in my Tomcat/CFML application when I visit the URL `www.someothername.com` I would expect to see in the CGI scope:

```
server_name: somename
```

but instead I get:

```
server_name: www.someothername.com
```

It's like the directive is totally ignored.

```
# Proxy CFML files to Tomcat
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /[^/:]+\.cfml*($|/)
RewriteRule (.*) ajp://%{HTTP_HOST}:8009$1 [P,L]
```

I also tried:

```
RewriteRule (.*) ajp://%{SERVER_NAME}:8009$1 [P,L]
```

and using mod_proxy instead of AJP:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8888$1 [P,L]
```

The last 2 cause a DNS lookup on `somename` but still returns `www.someothername.com` in the CGI.SERVER_NAME field

I should point out that the only reason I'm doing this is because I'm doing mass virtual-hosting with `mod_cfml` to automaticatically create tomcat contexts and I would like the context and application to use a short name derived from the vhost configuration. I guess I could just set a header (even rewrite the Host: header) but using ServerName seemed the most elegant solution.

UPDATE: There is something I noticed in the client headers that is probably relevant. There are 2 headers I haven't seen before:

```
x-forwarded-host: www.someothername.com
x-forwarded-server: somename
```

I need to know what set these headers and why. I'm assuming it was either Tomcat or mod_cfml. Can I rely on the `x-forwarded-server` value to always be ServerName?

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling a CGI, you're proxying, so trying to set SERVER_NAME is either useless or very close to it.

Typically with mass virtual hosting you should use the actual domain name that you received, which is HTTP_HOST, the `Host:` HTTP header, in your application to make the distinction.

Comment: That makes some sense except that CFML engines DO emulate CGI and provide a CGI scope containing the fields you would expect. For point 2 I do not want seperate "contexts" based on the FQDN used by the client. What I want is many FQDN aliases all pointing to the same "shortname" context. I do want to preserve the 'Host' header information but I need the "true" ServerName as well.

Comment: Hmm. You'll have to get it elsewhere, then, I think. Perhaps that mysterious header you mentioned? It should only take a moment to test whether that behaves the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks but I think you're too quick to assume the original server_name value isn't being passed through because this is "not CGI". I don't think that's the issue at all. I think it is being overwritten at some point in the httpd -> mod_proxy -> mod_cfml -> tomcat -> railo processing chain and I can probably prevent that if I knew where.